# ClassCastException being thrown while performing Manual Dependency Injection in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, classcastexception

I was trying to learn manual dependency injection using Android's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/manual#kotlin) on the same. Following, their example, I created these 4 basic classes.

**NumeralSquared.kt**

```
package com.example.dependency_injection_practice

import kotlin.math.pow

class NumeralSquared {

    fun getSquare(number: Double): Int {
        return number.pow(2).toInt()
    }

}
```

**Numeral.kt**

```
package com.example.dependency_injection_practice

class Numeral(private val numeralSquared: NumeralSquared) {

    private var number: Int = 0

    fun getNumber(): Int {
        number += 1

        return if (number % 2 == 0) {
            number
        } else {
            numeralSquared.getSquare(number.toDouble())
        }
    }
}
```

**AppContainer.kt**

```
package com.example.dependency_injection_practice

class AppContainer {

    private val numeralSquared = NumeralSquared()
    val numeral = Numeral(numeralSquared)

}
```

**MyApplication.kt**

```
package com.example.dependency_injection_practice

import android.app.Application

class MyApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var appContainer: AppContainer

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        appContainer = AppContainer()
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.dependency_injection_practice

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val appContainer = (application as MyApplication).appContainer
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I try to run this app, it returns to me, this error in the Logcat:

```
2021-04-06 10:20:16.201 8945-8945/com.example.dependency_injection_practice E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dependency_injection_practice, PID: 8945
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dependency_injection_practice/com.example.dependency_injection_practice.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.dependency_injection_practice.MyApplication
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.dependency_injection_practice.MyApplication
            at com.example.dependency_injection_practice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
            at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

The error points precisely at this line:

```
    val appContainer = (application as MyApplication).appContainer
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out the error. I tried to follow the documentation's instructions appropriately and checked it multiple times. I also searched on Stack Overflow for similar issues but couldn't find any.

Could someone please help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you have manifest entry for `MyApplication`?

Comment: I suspect the same as @ADM. Your application tag should look something like this.  <application
        android:name="MyApplication" ...>

Comment: It worked! Thank you both for the help.